# How to remove certain elements from a list?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, indexing

I have a list that contains character vectors. I would like to remove elements in these vectors that are equal to "J" or "Co". Here's a look at my list:

```
> fh_mentioned[1:10]  
[[1]]
[1] "Co"

[[2]]
[1] "Oscar de la Renta" "Balmain"           "J"                

[[3]]
[1] "Co" "Co"

[[4]]
[1] "Christian Dior" "J"              "Dior"          

[[5]]
[1] "Christian Lacroix" "J"                

[[6]]
[1] "Louis Féraud" "Féraud"       "Burberry"     "Bally"        "Féraud"       "Féraud"      

[[7]]
[1] "J"        "Givenchy" "Givenchy" "Givenchy" "Givenchy"

[[8]]
[1] "J"

[[9]]
[1] "Vogue"             "Phi"               "Valentino"         "Alexander McQueen" "Olivier Theyskens" "Co"               

[[10]]
[1] "Yves Saint Laurent" "Co"                 "Saint Laurent"      "Co"                 "Saint Laurent"
```

I tried:

```
for(i in 1:length(fh_mentioned_clean)){
for(j in 1:length(fh_mentioned_clean[[i]])){
 fh_mentioned_clean[[i]] <- fh_mentioned_clean[[i]][fh_mentioned_clean[[i]][j] != "J" &
                                                      fh_mentioned_clean[[i]][j] != "Co"]
}
}
```

to no avail.

I also tried an if statement in the loop by setting those unwanted elements to NULL but it did not work because some elements are character(0) for some reason.

Comment: Try `lapply(fh_mentioned_clean, setdiff, y = c("J", "Co"))` to remove those elements from the vector.  If you need to remove the list element completely if the only element is 'J' or 'Co', `Filter(function(x) !(all(x =="J")|all(x == "Co")), fh_mentioned_clean)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working like a charm! You saved me a ton of time.